# Ordenar en una consulta con agrupación de Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Quiero ***ordenar los resultados de una consulta Eloquent con agrupación alfabéticamente***.

Lo estoy haciendo sobre la colección resultante de la consulta:

```
return Log::groupBy('type')
    ->get('type')

    ->sortBy('type')
    ->pluck('type')
    ->toArray();
```

Para ordenarlos en la consulta he intentado (no funciona):

```
return Log::groupBy('type')
    ->orderBy('type')
    ->get('type')

    ->pluck('type')
    ->toArray();
```

> Editado:

También he reordenado de la consulta (orderBy / groupBy):

```
return Log::orderBy('type')
    ->groupBy('type')
    ->get('type')

    ->pluck('type')
    ->toArray();
```

En ambos casos se ejecuta sin errores, pero no ordena.

*PD: Estoy en Laravel 7, con una BD MariaDB 10.1.47.*

Comment: Intenta cambiando el orden: `return Log::orderBy('type')->groupBy('type')->pluck('type')->toArray()`

Comment: @JuanRivera ya lo probé, funciona igual que siguiendo el orden que indique.

Comment: Pero que no te funciona? No te ordena correctamente? Sale un error?

Comment: @JuanRivera No hay errores, simplemente no ordena.

Comment: Prueba ponerle al orderBy el tipo de orden, o sea descendente o ascendente: orderBy('type', 'desc')